# Joomla 1.6.1 zeros configuration.php file

Tags: configuration, joomla

I have downloaded Joomla 1.6.1 and tried to install in on Ubuntu (latest apache/php/etc)
I unzip and untar the archive in my web root folder for the vhost I have defined. (Vhost works ok, I put a phpinfo test file in there and all the configs look right)

I then go to the index page and follow all the prompts to configure the Joomla site. Once I get to the last page the one that has the button to remove the install folder I press that and the folder is removed.

The problem is that the configuration.php file is empty (size 0).

I have repeated the process and I have tried to also copy the default config from the install folder and move it to the web root and just skip the installer all together but when I do that and I go and save some of the global settings the configuration.php file is zeroed again.

I have also tried to do a chown www-data.www-data recursively on all files as well as chmod 775 recursively (www-data is user and group of apache web service)

No errors come up in the apache log file and no php errors come up.

Ran out of ideas ... :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if there is a remove button? You should go to your joomla folder and delete the whole installation folder manually and then refresh your page, it should work.